# PHP Indica que esta intentando asignar 56864191 bytes cuando memory_limit esta en 134217728 bytes

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel me está lanzando un error de PHP en el registro de errores que no es razonable, porque indica que está intentando asignar menos cantidad de datos que lo que php_memory_limit tiene configurado.

El error es el siguiente:
[Fri Apr 26 12:55:30 2019] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 56864191 bytes) in C:\Users\xxx\Desktop\xxxx\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Support\Str.php on line 338

Estamos usando PHP 7.1.28 y Laravel 5.6.28

La línea 338 es:

```
    return substr_replace($subject, $replace, $position, strlen($search));
```

Está dentro de esta funcion:

```
public static function replaceFirst($search, $replace, $subject)
    {
        if ($search == '') {
            return $subject;
        }

        $position = strpos($subject, $search);

        if ($position !== false) {
            return substr_replace($subject, $replace, $position, strlen($search));
        }

        return $subject;
    }
```

El controlador problemático es este:

```
public function loginPAEC(Request $request)
    {   
        $xml = new \SimpleXMLElement($request->xml);
        $datosAFIP = json_decode(json_encode($xml), true);

        //valido que este registrado antes de realizar el login. De estar registrado, solo se hara el login        
        $authObject = new \StdClass();
        $authObject->cuilcuit = $datosAFIP['operation']['login']['@attributes']['uid']; //podria ser entity en lugar de uid
        $authObject->password = $datosAFIP['id']['@attributes']['unique_id'];

        $datosLoginRegister = $this->generarRespuestaUsuario($authObject);

        return response()->json($datosLoginRegister);
    }
```

Comment: El log es bastante claro: Eso quiere decir que ya está ocupada X cantidad de memoria y que lo que queda no es suficiente para lo que se desea asignar. Es como si tuvieras 5 estacionamientos, necesitas 3 pero ya tienes ocupados 3.

Comment: @Shaz Sí, el log es claro, pero si subi el valor de memory_size el error se sigue reproduciendo

Comment: La solución no consiste en subir y subir más memoria, podríamos tener 64GB y tal vez siga fallando. La idea es encontrar el error en el código. Algo de debugging ayuda.

Comment: Cómo hago el debugging?

Comment: añade algo de informacion, por ejemplo el codigo dle archivo Str.php que te indica el log. A ver si hay algun bucle o algo que empiece a cargar informacion y te desborda la memoria.

Comment: @Jakala edité mi pregunte y añadí mas info sobre el error tal como solicitas.

Comment: Un problema puede ser que se esté almacenando muchos datos en sesión. Esto me paso en un trabajo, otra persona estaba guardando muchos datos en sesión al ingresar a un script y de ahí daba ese error hasta que se limpieba.

Comment: @DamiánAlva muchas gracias por tu aporte! en este caso yo solo estoy tratando de mover un codigo que funciona correctamente en mi computadora hacia otra computadora, es decir, ese mismo codigo fucniona bien en mi computadora pero no en la computadora a donde lo estoy intentando mover

Answer (score -1):

Puedes colocar al inicio de tu codigo esto:

```
 ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
```

Eso hara que PHP pueda usar la memoria disponible del equipo.

Lo otro saeria revisar el codigo que esta produciendo el error y tratar de optmizarlo.

Comment: Esto desata el mismo error 500 al pegarle a la ruta de la API pero hace que Laravel deje de reportarme en el LOG y en la consola el error Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted.